# How do I comment an entire file in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm trying to comment an entire file describing an overall functionality. I put something like this at the top of each file

```
/**
 * @file File with helper functions that facilitate reading config JSON files.
 */
```

but when I generate the documentation I end up with a weird Index headline before every file. It looks like this:

[image]

I didn't make any changes to default JSDoc configuration. Am I doing something wrong? What's that Index headline? Can I get rid of it or change it to something meaningful?